# How to add data to parse relation column in parse dashboard (Programatically)?

Tags: android, parse-platform

Suppose i am having a column in parse dashboard named "vendorInv" of "Vendors" class which is a parse relation pointing to class "B".
Now i can add data to parse relation in parse dashboard.
But the problem is I am unable to add data to relation column programatically in android  (below is my tried snippet ).
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
ParseObject productDetails = new ParseObject("B");


        productDetails.put("productMrp", 1337 + "Rs");
        productDetails.put("productName", "Rbk");
        productDetails.put("productDetails", "sjhkfdasfuafhkajfh");
        productDetails.put("size", "xl");

        ParseObject pd = ParseObject.createWithoutData("Vendors", objId);
        ParseRelation<ParseObject> pr = pd.getRelation("vendorInv");
        pr.add(productDetails);

        /*pd.put("vendorInv", productDetails);*/
        pd.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.i("Parse", "Save Succeeded");
                } else {
                    Log.i("Parse", e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

**error**: Parse: com.parse.ParseException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unable to encode an association with an unsaved ParseObject
 **SOLVED** `

```
ParseObject productDetails = new ParseObject("VendorInv");

            productDetails.put("productMrp", 25555 + "Rs");
            productDetails.put("productName", "Clb");
            productDetails.put("productDetails", "sjhkfdasfuafhkajfh");
            productDetails.put("size", "xl");
            try {
                productDetails.save();
                String obj = productDetails.getObjectId();

                ParseObject pd = ParseObject.createWithoutData("Vendors", objId);

                ParseRelation<ParseObject> pr = pd.getRelation("vendorInv");

                pr.add(ParseObject.createWithoutData("VendorInv", obj));

                pd.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Log.i("Parse", "Save Succeeded");
                        } else {
                            Log.i("Parse", e.toString());
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }`
```

Comment: Parse service is shutdown right ? Would recommend firebase.

Comment: no its open source now and using mongo db